# Ethereum constructor confusion

Tags: solidity

when I deploy using Truffle, the contract constructor gets called right? and in there I can set
`owner = msg.sender`

Now on the client side, using web3 in javascript when I do something like:

```
window.ethereum.enable().then((accounts)=>{
        contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, "0x2c2D9E87eCFbCb9758df8cf063C71d3C9DBE5304", {from : accounts[1]});
        console.log("contractInstance", contractInstance);
    });
```

does this also call the constructor ? or is this a different situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not.  The constructor is called when you deploy (migrate) your contract to the blockchain.